# Prove that for a fractional linear transformation $f(z)$ such that $f(\Bbb{R})=\Bbb{R}$ we have $f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ with $a,b,c,d\in \Bbb{R}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, linear-fractional-transformation

> Let $f(z)$ be a fractional linear transformation such that $f(\Bbb{R})=\Bbb{R}$. I want to show that $f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ $a,b,c,d\in \Bbb{R}$.

We have given a solution in class, where they distinguish into the following cases

1. $c,d\neq 0$
2. $c=0$
3. $d=0$

If I have the cases it is clear to me how they proceeded but I don't see how we get to those cases and why they are sufficient.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If $a,b,c,d$ are not already restricted to $\mathbb R$, what *is* the restriction on their values?

Comment: Note that replacing $(a,b,c,d)$ by $(ka,kb,kc,kd)$ for a non-zero complex number leaves $f$ unchanged. So, a more appropriate question would be whether $a,b,c,d$ can be chosen to be real. Also, I don't think the case division given in OP is not a necessity, but rather a. convenience.

Comment: If both $c=0,\ d=0$ then for any $z$ your $f(z)$ would be a fraction with $0$ denominator and thus be undefined.

Comment: @Andreas I changed the question a bit is it now clearer?

Comment: @SangchulLee yes but what I don't see is how to get to this convenience because I would never come up with these cases or any cases without forgetting one

Comment: Perhaps the assumption should be replaced by $f(\mathbb{R}\cup \{\infty\})=\mathbb{R}\cup \{\infty\}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will replace the assumption by $$f(\mathbb{R}\cup \{\infty\})=\mathbb{R}\cup \{\infty\}$$
We have $ad-bc\neq 0,$ as otherwise the function $f$ is constant.

1. $a,c\neq 0.$

Thus $$f(x)={a\over c}\ {x+{b\over a}\over x+{d\over c}}$$

Substituting $x=\infty $ gives $\alpha :={a\over c}\in \mathbb{R}.$ Next the values $0$ and $\infty $ are attained at $\beta:=-{b\over a}$ and  $\gamma:=-{d\over c},$ respectively. Hence $\beta,\,\gamma \in \mathbb{R}.$ Thus $$f(x)=\alpha {x-\beta\over x-\gamma}\qquad \alpha\,,\beta\,,\gamma \in\mathbb{R}$$

2. $c=0$

Then $a\neq 0$ and
$$f(x)=f(0)\,(1-x)+f(1)\,x$$
Hence the coefficients are real numbers.

3. $a=0$

Then $c\neq 0.$ For $g(x)=(f(x))^{-1}$ we get $$g(x)=g(0)\,(1-x)+g(1)\,x$$ Thus the coefficients of $g(x),$ and consequently of $f(x),$ are real

Comment: Ah and then I don't need to take $b=0$ and $d=0$ and $b,d\neq0$ since this is symmetric

Comment: All cases were taken into account as either $a,c\neq 0$ or $ac=0.$ There is no need to do anything else.

Comment: but $ac$ can't be equal to zero

Comment: $f(z)=z,$ i.e. $c=0.$ Also $g(z)=1/z,$ i.e. $a=0.$

Comment: but if $f$ is an FLT and $ac=0$ then $ad-bc=0$ which contradicts that $f$ is an FLT

Comment: $ac=0$ is equivalent to $a=0$ or $c=0.$ They cannot be $0$ at the same time.

Comment: why can't they be zero at the same time? So I mean yes then it would not be a FLT anymore but in general is it because $\Bbb{C}$ is a integral domain?

Comment: Even if $a=c=0$ the coefficients are real, as $b/d$ must be real. Although in this case the range of the function is  properly contained in  $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}.$